# how do i name the outputs / results of a function in R

Tags: r, function

straight to the point... im very new to R and I just wrote my first "cheap" :) function which is:

```
Holzrezeptur <- function(Spana, u, LG, FGL, HG, FGH) {
  if (u > 10) {
    warning("Ausgleichsfeuchtigkeit liegt über 10%")
  }
  Spanlut <- Spana*(1 + u/100)
  Leimfl <- (Spana*(LG/100))*(100/FGL)
  Haerterfl <- (Leimfl*(FGL/100)*HG/100)*(1000/FGH)
  out <- c(Spanlut, Leimfl, Haerterfl)
  return(out)
}

Holzrezeptur(1800, 4, 8, 60, 3, 30)

##[1] 1872  240  144
```

..forgive me that this is written in German respectively my English at all :). its a simplified method about how to get a mixture to create specific chipboards for certain wood moisture.

to my question:
my three outputs are "Spanlut", "Leimfl" and "Haerterfl" and for those I wanna name the output/result in the end.

so the result should NOT be:

```
##[1] 1872  240  144
```

but more like:

```
## Spanlutro Leimfluessig Haerterfluessig
##      1872          240             144
```

the simpler the best! :)

if I had an approach I would post it, but I got no idea how to start with.
(may I write it directly into the binding!?)
im quite sure for most of u this is just a fingerexercise so I hope to get response for my little concern.
I rly hope I don't bore you :)
and thank u very much for your help.

With best regards
-db-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the names while combining the outputs. One way to do this is to create a dataframe.

You can try:

```
Holzrezeptur <- function(Spana, u, LG, FGL, HG, FGH) {
  if (u > 10) {
   warning("Ausgleichsfeuchtigkeit liegt über 10%")
  }
Spanlut <- Spana*(1 + u/100)
Leimfl <- (Spana*(LG/100))*(100/FGL)
Haerterfl <- (Leimfl*(FGL/100)*HG/100)*(1000/FGH)
out <- data.frame(Spanlutro =Spanlut
                   , Leimfluessig  = Leimfl
                   , Haerterfluessig = Haerterfl)
return(out)
}
```

Comment: Dear Aramis7d
smooth, working, a command I already know of, perfect solution resp answer.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Bandit glad to know. If it solved your query, please feel free to have look here `http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers`

Answer (score 0):

easiest solution: `out <- list(Spanlut=Spanlut, Leimfl=Leimfl, Haerterfl=Haerterfl)`

Comment: Dear persimmon_jones
naaaa too easy! :) hehe just joking; thank u as well for this alternative!